# How to scroll effect with scrollmagic?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, effect, scrollmagic

how do build this scroll effect which be found on
[scrollmagic.io](http://scrollmagic.io)?
If you scroll a certain distance the blue screen changes in to a white screen.

Comment: I tried to figure it out which example was used but the documentation is so lousy i didnt find anything.If somebody could point me the example out and maybe which variable need to be modified it would be a great help. thank you

Comment: Here are examples: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/index.html